# Drawing multiple chart in php with mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, charts

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Lt3.png)

[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7RbM.png)

| lokasi | jan | feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sukajaya | 652 | 427 |
| kenten laut | 123 | 532 |
| mariana | 126 | 439 |

i'm trying to insert more than one chart into php, but it doenst seem to work if I just add similiar code, any clue of what should I do or should I change my method to make a chart

editeed: I want to make more than one chart (not multibar chart), so 2 different chart with same label(using lokasi) but different data (using jan, feb etc)

```
<?php 
  $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dinkes');
  $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM data2022");

  foreach($query as $data)
  {
    $lokasi[] = $data['lokasi'];
    $januari[] = $data['jan'];
?>
<div style="width: 500px;">
  <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
  <script>            
              const labels = <?php echo json_encode($lokasi) ?>;
              const data = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                  label: 'Pengidap Penyakit ISPA Januari',
                  data: <?php echo json_encode($januari) ?>,
                  backgroundColor: []
                }]
              };

              const config = {
                type: 'bar',
                data: data,
                options: {
                  scales: {
                    y: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                    }
                  }
                },
              };

              var myChart1 = new Chart(
                document.getElementById('myChart1'),
                config
              );
              </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a useful problem description. What happens when you try?

Comment: You shouldn't use the same variables each time through the loop. And you're putting all the charts at the same ID `myChart1`.

Comment: so my intention is to create more than one chart with different row for the data

with $data['lokasi'] as the label and use $data['jan']/feb/etc as the data
so it makes  multiple chart with different data (one chart use jan, then feb, then mar)

I tried to add $februari[] = $data['feb']; adn copied the script with changed data
but it doesnt seem to work (it doesnt appear)

Comment: I can't answer any more because I don't know the Chart API.

Comment: Put all the results in a 2-dimensional PHP array using `$data = $query->fetch_all()`. Use `array_column($data, 'lokasi')` to get all the labels. Then loop over the months, and use `array_column($data, $month)` to get the values for each label. For each month in the loop you can make a chart.